# Matlab plot segment [limited lines by two points]

Tags: matlab, plot, line

I googled it...

And all i found was how to plot a line that crosses two points, what i need is Segment (**Line that crosses two points A(x1, y1) and B(x2, y2) but limited with those two points**) if somebody can give me a function that does that, i will thankful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do what you wanted using a simple plot command.

```
A = [6,3];
B = [2,4];
plot(A,B);
axis([0,10,0,5]);
```

[image]